# JPQL CONCAT Function is Boolean instead of String

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I've been looking for a concrete answer for the foolwing issue, but I haven't found anything that actually helps. Here's The Issue:

On WebLogic Server version 12.2.1.2 and 12.2.1.3.
while creating a query like with JPA application

```
SELECT NEW model.ReturnType(a.id, a.name, CONCAT(a.name, a.id)) FROM EntityA a
```

throws the following exception:

> Exception Description: An Exception was thrown while executing a
>   ReportQuery with a constructor expression:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: model.ReturnType.(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean) Internal Exception:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: model.ReturnType.(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean) Query:
>   ReportQuery(name="MyClassConcat" referenceClass=EntityA jpql=" SELECT
>   NEW model.ReturnType(a.id, a.name, CONCAT(a.name, a.id)) FROM EntityA
>   a ") at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDatabaseQueryInternal(QueryImpl.java:344)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1135)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1155)

The return type for CONCAT should be String, not Boolean.

Any idea why this is happening? And how to use CONCAT in my query so it can be read as a String instead of a Boolean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of (already fixed) bug reported in [512386](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=512386). Detailed reason can be found from [diff](https://git.eclipse.org/c/eclipselink/eclipselink.runtime.git/commit/?id=bccadb77ecc625871b3303c7851c63f05917b270).

Because bug was fixed quite a while ago, I assume there is patch available. If not, then one have to fall back to update library or change persistence provider entirely.